# PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR: Syntax error at or near 'VACUUM'

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I tried to VACUUM a delta table, but there is a Syntax error.

Here is the code:

```
%sql
set spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled = False
VACUUM test_deltatable
```

Comment: try to add `;` after `set` command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing your code gives the following error:

```sql
set spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled = False
VACUUM test_deltatable

IllegalArgumentException: spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled should be Boolean, but was False
```

As the [Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott) correctly pointed, adding `;` (semicolon) fixes it:

```sql
set spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled = False;
VACUUM test_deltatable
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'VACUUM'(line 3, pos 0)

== SQL ==
VACUUM test_deltatable RETAIN 20
^^^
```

it was due to missing `HOURS` at end.

So `VACUUM test_deltatable RETAIN 20 HOURS` worked fine.